# Prove that there are prime numbers such as $p_{i}$ such that $A = p_{1}^{a_{1}}*p_{2}^{a_{2}} * ... * p_{k}^{a_{k}} , a_{i}> 0 $

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, integers

### A and B are natural numbers.

Prove that there are prime numbers such as $p_{i}$ such that   $A = p_{1}^{a_{1}}*p_{2}^{a_{2}} * ... * p_{k}^{a_{k}} , a_{i}> 0 $

---

Then we consider $ B = p_{1}^{b_{1}}*p_{2}^{b_{2}}*...*p_{k}^{b_{k}}$ , prove that $ (a,b) = p_{1}^{c_{1}}*...*p_{k}^{c_{k}} --- c_{i} = min (a_{i} , b_{i})$ , and $[a,b]=p_{1}^{d_{1}}*...*p_{k}^{d_{k}}--- d_{i}= max(a_{i},b_{i})$ . for all : 1<= i <= k

---

*notice:* The first part of the proof originates directly from the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, but I have no idea for the second part of the prove, thanks for your help

Comment: Search: unique factorization, gcd, and lcm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to prove the existence and uniqueness of the prime factorization of any natural number.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746568/how-to-prove-the-existence-and-uniqueness-of-the-prime-factorization-of-any-natu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Induction hypothesis misunderstanding and the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852764/induction-hypothesis-misunderstanding-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-arithmetic)

Comment: The proof that you are looking for is **not short**.  Further, it is a standard result in number theory, involving such intermediate results as that any common divisor $r$ of $(a,b)$ is also a divisor of the gcd$(a,b)$.  In my opinion, the way to nail down the validity of your assertion is by finding a number theory book and starting on page 1.

Answer (score 0):

For each prime $p$, you can talk about the *multiplicity* with which the prime occurs in a given natural number.  For example $8$ has multiplicity $3$ at the prime $2$, and it has multiplicity $0$ at every other prime.

It's not difficult to see that a natural number $n$ is divisible by another natural number $m$ if and only if at each prime $p$, the multiplicity of $p$ in $n$ is greater than or equal to the multiplicity of $p$ in $m$.

Using this principle, it is pretty straightforward to interpret greatest common divisor and least common multiple in terms of prime factorizations.